# How JMS producer/consumer/broker makes it sure/ack that message is sent/delievered/consumed/processed

Tags: java, jms, message-listener

1.How JMS producer gets acknowledgment that message is sent successfully to Broker/MOM/JMS Server.
2.How JMS producer gets acknowledgment that message is delivered successfully to the consumer(in both sync and async case)
3.How JMS Consumer makes it sure that message is read successfully to broker and producer.
Is it AUTO_Acknowledgment ?
4.How JMS Consumer makes it sure that message is processed successfully to broker and producer.
Is it AUTO_Acknowledgment ?

Answer (score 1):

JMS is an Async environment, implementing a fire and forget methodology. If you need a reply, you might want to implement a temp queue with Reply-To. This is how you can get feedback from the consumer to the producer.